# the team has already reached the maximum number of iPhone devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm no longer registered as a paid Apple developer, but now we can push our own apps on our device via Xcode.
I recently try to push my app to my friend iPhone and it works great, but now I cannot push it anywhere. I tried my own iPhone and another one, it prompts me with the same message:

> Unable to add device 'iPhone de xx_me_xx*' because the team has already reached the maximum number of iPhone devices.
>   Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Developer: xxx_me_xxx".
>   Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't include the currently selected device "iPhone de xxx_meagain_xxx".
>   Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'

As I understand, I cannot find the place to remove device from my account nor the place to edit provisioning profile.
My iPhone has the latest iOS version as my mac and Xcode.

Comment: It's in your iTunes account under provisioning profiles, remove the devices that no longer apply to your needs .. not a programming related question and needs to be asked somewhere more appropriate.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you can only do this once a year. So make sure the list is cleaned up appropriately when you do this. If you haven't done it for the year, you can remove them on your developer's account.

Log into your account at https://developer.apple.com, go to Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles > Identfier's All Devices section.

Comment: the website is different now, i don't know where to find the certificate section